# Python objects implementation

Tags: python, oop, virtual-machine, cpython, python-internals

I am studying the CPython's objects system implementation and I struggling to understand the differences between and purposes of the `PyTypeObject` and `PyType_Type` structs.

At first sight, I thought that `PyTypeObject` structs would hold the information common to all objects of a certain class. However, `PyTypeObject` structs have an attributes dictionary (`tp_dict`) and it would not make sense to have all objects of a certain class share same dicitionary. So I am starting to think that `PyTypeObject`s are more like molds that are created with dummy values when an object is created and then filled with custom attributes' values later (upon `tp_init`'s call, for example). It seems to me that these molds are created with the information stored in the `PyType_Type` struct of the objects type.

Even though this second interpretation makes more sense than the first one I thought about, it does not seem like that is what really happens for the implementation of Tuples have only a single struct, all of which have `tp_name` set to `"tuple"` and not to `"type"`.

What are the purposes of `PyTypeObject` structs and `PyType_Type` structs and where are the attributes of a certain object stored?

Comment: In Python, types are objects too. And because objects use a dict to hold their fields (except for `__slots__`), I am not surprised that types have a dict like regular instances. And when you define a class in Python, you (usually) provide some methods, which will get bound when an instance is created, but the type itself holds the "raw" methods (that you still can call `MyClass.some_method(instance_as_self)` works fine. I remember having read how they worked a few years ago, but I don't recall enough to help you without committing the time to read again myself.